Delete data from a specific partition
Background
Hoping to be able to delete data from a specific partition in a partitioned table in SQL Server 2019.
I have a table partitioned on [Source] column, and need to delete some of the rows within a particular column, therefore I need a WHERE clause and cannot use the TRUNCATE WITH (PARTION).
Example
DELETE FROM [table] WHERE source = 'A' AND set = '123'

The Issue
The main issue is that multiple jobs can be running on this table at the same time.
Therefore, I need the lock_escalation to be at partition level, so that if an insert is being run for one [Source], a delete can be run for a different [source] at the same time.
I worry that there isn't a clear solution for this.
Other info
Only related question I could find was here from nearly 6 years so.
Is this possible, or do I need to amend the partition configuration?
Any suggestions are much appreciated.

I'm probably missing something as this is somewhat at the edge of my knowledge of SQL Server, but can you clarify why the partitions are relevant? Why not just DELETE FROM [Table] WHERE ...?

If you're worried about specific rows, just DELETE the rows and don't worry about the partition. SQL Server will do the right thing. If you're worried about the Source column, include that as one of the conditional in the WHERE clause.

@esqew maybe he wants the truncate performance and lock avoidance.

Yes, the issue is that multiple jobs can be running on this table at the same time. I need the lock_escalation to be partition level, so that if an insert is being run, a delete can be run at the same time. I will edit my question to clarify this, sorry for the confusion.

Is it acceptable that data is missing during some window? you could probably do a switch out => copy table => delete from copy => switch back in. For your question, you can just use WHERE Source = $PARTITION.SomeFunc(someCol) = <your part number>
